# R Split series into month

Tags: r, time-series, lubridate

I have the below data with date and count. Please help in transforming this one row where months are columns. And rows are data of each year

```
Date       count
=================  
2011-01-01 10578
2011-02-01  9330
2011-03-01 10686
2011-04-01 10260
2011-05-01 10032
2011-06-01  9762
2011-07-01 10308
2011-08-01  9966
2011-09-01 10146
2011-10-01 10218
2011-11-01  8826
2011-12-01  9504
to    
       JAN   FEB      MAR    APR   MAY  JUN   JUL  AUG  SEP    OCT NOV   DEC  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2011  10578   9330   10686 10260 10032 9762 10308 9966 10146 10218 8826 9504
2012 ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfect task for `ts` in R base. Suppose your data.frame is `x`then using `ts` will produce the output you want.

```
> ts(x$count, start=c(2011,01,01), end=c(2011,12,01), frequency=12)
       Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   May   Jun   Jul   Aug   Sep   Oct   Nov   Dec
2011 10578  9330 10686 10260 10032  9762 10308  9966 10146 10218  8826  9504
```

Answer (score 1):

If your data is in `x` try something like this:

```
library(reshape2)
res <- dcast(transform(x, month = format(Date, format="%m"),
                       year = format(Date, "%Y")),
             year ~ month, value.var="count")
rownames(res) <- res$year
res <- res[,-1]
names(res) <- toupper(month.abb[as.numeric(names(res))])
res
```

This assumes that `x$Date` is already a date. If not, you will need to first convert is to a date:

```
x$Date <- as.Date(x$Date)
```

Comment: Data was split properly. But months are not in order.      ` Apr  Aug  Dec  Feb   Jan   Jul  Jun   Mar   May  Nov   Oct   Sep`
`2011` `10260 9966 9504 9330 10578 10308 9762 10686 10032 8826 10218 10146`

Comment: I have fixed it, but I do prefer the `ts` answer!